# Do gable end rafters have to meet at a ridge board if the rest do?

Tags: roof, shed

On a shed roof, can the gable end rafters touch without ridge board, and then ridge board be connected in between them for rest of rafters?

This would be for ease of raising gable ends.

Comment: Yes. If you want much more than that, you'll have to be more specific. If the rafters are tied, then this is no big deal at all. You would just have to develop some strength where they touch so that unbalanced roof loads don't cause the rafters to slide across each other. I assume that there's wall sheathing all over the gable end, so there's your strength.

Comment: Yes there would be t1-11 sheathing on the outside, and I would put a collar tie and or rafter tie. I usually build them with a ridge board, but my thought is by having the gable end rafters touch, I can sheath the wall on the ground, raise them, and then set my ridge board in between them and run the rest of my rafters along the ridge board as normal. I would essentially be shooting the ridge board to the edges of the two gable rafters, making the ridge board 1 1/2” shorter on each end. Just trying to portray what my idea is. Thanks for the response!

Comment: how it a shed roof the there are rafters from two sides?

Comment: How big is the shed? I built mine with a gambrel roof with home-built trusses and no ridge board at all for a 10' x 14' shed.

Comment: @Jasen I think the OP means "a roof for a shed", not a "shed roof" (which has a high point on one side and a low point on the other with a single slope). It seems pretty apparent that this shed will have a high point in the middle.